# How to use File.new() in Rails app to create a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create some_javascript_file.js after a user submits a form and save this file in the public directory of my app.

When testing this localy I can simply use File.new("./public/some_javascript_file.js", "w") to accomplish this but this solution doesn't work when the app is deployed to Heroku.

Please would you have any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how Heroku works. Basically, as stated [in the docs](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), the filesystem is ephemeral and you can't rely on it. If you want persistence, you should upload this JS file to some external service, such as AWS S3. Or you might want to deploy your app to a different environment, such as self-managed VPS, where filesystem is real and your file won't disappear.